# Issue with a while loop using GMP

Tags: c++, c, loops, gmp

I'm trying to code the extended Euclidean algorithm using the **GMP library** because I'm using large numbers. My algorithm is the basic one, just adapted for GMP numbers.

But I have a problem with my while loop. The code below is a minable reproducible example of my algorithm. I changed the content of the loop just for testing.

```
void euclid(mpz_t a, mpz_t b){


mpz_t r1, r2, u1, u2, v1, v2;

mpz_init_set_ui(u1, 1);
mpz_init_set_ui(v1, 0);
mpz_init_set_ui(u2, 0);
mpz_init_set_ui(v2, 1);

mpz_inits(r1, r2);

mpz_set(r1, a);
mpz_set(r2, b);

while(mpz_cmp_ui(r2, 0))
{
    gmp_printf("r2 : %Zd\n", r2);
    mpz_sub_ui(r2, r2, 1);

    mpz_t q;
    mpz_init(q);
}}
```

**The loop doesn't seem to be executed**.

Looking for the origin of the problem, I tried to simplify the loop and I get a problem (the loop doesn't execute anymore) whenever I add the line "mpz_init(q);". I called my function euclid with a equal to mpz_t 33 and b equal to mpz_t 5.

Comment: What is `r2`? How is it initialized? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I will edit my message. r2 is a mpz_t vaiable. I initialize its value before the loop with mpz_init(r2) and set its value  with mpz_set(r2,e) where e is an argument of my function.

Comment: If the loop doesn't seem to execute, it can only be because `r2` is equal to `0` (as then [`mpz_cmp_ui`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Comparisons.html) will return zero, which is "false")

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree with that, but the simple fact of adding the line mpz_init(q) makes the loop not executed anymore. Without that line, the loop is well executed. So I don't understand how this line ("mpz_init(q)") can have an impact on the value of r2.

Comment: Still, [mcve] is in order, including where and how exactly you add the init line that affects the results.

Comment: Without initialization, the value of `r2` is *indeterminate*, it's unknown, and very likely not equal to `0`. In C++ using such a value leads to *undefined behavior*. The `mpz_init` function explicitly set the value to `0`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, but after the call to `mpz_init`, I use the function `mpz_set` to set a value different from `0` to `r2`.

Comment: Have you seen `mpz_gcdext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems like this ("I added a seemingly irrelevant variable/function call and the behaviour changed mysteriously") are almost always the result of Undefined Behaviour. In this case, the UB is in the line

```
mpz_inits(r1, r2);
```

which should have been

```
mpz_inits(r1, r2, NULL);
```

(See the [docs](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers.html)). The list given to `mpz_inits` must be NULL-terminated so that the function knows when to stop; otherwise it will overwrite random memory.

Valgrind is an invaluable tool for uncovering this kind of issue.